# How do I use datetimepicker() for different element with same Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In my code a certain **div** element will be generated dynamically using jQuery. So I took a copy of that **div** element using .html() and appended it. Now in that **div** I have a **date** field where I must use **datetimepicker()**. Now I found that **datetimepicker** is not working for different element with same ID.

Here is a demo snippet.

```
<!--testing-->
        <div id='testdate'>
            <div class='input-group date' id='recoverydate2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Select year" id="rcv_date" name="year" value="<?php echo $gde_date;?>" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class='input-group date' id='recoverydate2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Select year" id="rcv_date" name="year" value="<?php echo $gde_date;?>" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div> -->
        </div>
 <!--testing-->
```

The 2nd commented **div** element would get generated dynamically. So I have to make **datetimepicker()** work for both of them.

Here is the JS

```
$(#recoverydate2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
});
```

Though I have tried this to make both of them work, but didnt work.

```
$('#testdate #recoverydate2:eq(0)').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
});
$('#testdate #recoverydate2:eq(1)').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
});
```

Comment: You don't. IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique, can't you just modify the generated id to make it different?

Comment: Well I am also thinking of it but actually this div is only for testing the actuall div which I have to generate is quite large if u want to see the whole I can forword it. So when I am cloning that whole div I cannot reach the inner div where I would change the ID.

Comment: By the way will it be ok to use same class instead to ID? Will it work in this case?

Comment: Yeah, same class will work fine. But you have to be careful not to use that class elsewhere.

Comment: @VTodorov Thanks buddy. I must say I missed this simple trick. It worked. Hope it will work my actual work too.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple elements with the same ids are not valid HTML. That's why `class`  exists! That said, you can create a copy of the `div` with a new id.

For example :

```
$('#testdate').append(
  '<div class="input-group date" id="recoverydate2-generated">' +
  $('#recoverydate2').html() +
  '</div>'
);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: No actually I cannot do this because this code is just for testing  the actual div which I have to generate is quite large if u want to see the whole I can forword it. So when I am cloning that whole div I cannot reach the inner div where I would change the ID.